# How to change background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to fade out background color when focus in;

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.skiplink').focusin(function(){       
           $('#skip').attr('tabindex','-1');
           $('#skip').focusin(function(){
               $('#skip').css({backgroundColor:"green"}).animate({backgroundColor:"#f6f6f6"},300);
            });
       });
        $('#skip').focusout(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');
        });
    });
```

It worked with Chrome, but in FireFox and IE edge, I couldn't see the color green. It changed to #f6f6f6 without showing green.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're attaching a `focusin` event handler within another event handler - dont do that, just one level of event handlers

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. Could you show me the details? Thanks.

Comment: Assign $('#skip') to a variable and use it. It will save a ton of time for you and for others who work with you.

Comment: try `.css('background-color', 'green')` instead of `.css({backgroundColor:"green"})`

Comment: @devlincarnate those will both do the same thing

Comment: @phpmyadmin2014 What are you trying to accomplish by nesting the event handlers?

Comment: I want to make the background color disappear as soon as the #skip got focus in when I use my tab key in keyboard.